# sbt doesn't recognize ScalaTest Table-driven property checks as tests

Tags: unit-testing, scala, junit, sbt, scalatest

I wrote some [ScalaTest Table-driven property checks](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/table_driven_property_checks) and I'm trying to run them with `sbt test`. Looking at the report I see that `ScalaTest` can recognize all the `JUnit` tests I have (they are in the same class as the checks), it runs property checks (i.e., `forAll` body), but it doesn't treat `forAll` as a test. If it fails I see the stack trace in the report (with `ScalaTest` failed test exception) and `sbt` says there was an "error" during the test run, but it says that all of the tests passed. The total number of tests in the report includes only `JUnit` tests.

Is there the support for this style of tests in `sbt`?

Answer (score 8):

forAll in PropertyChecks is not a test. It is essentially a glorified assertion. You need to place assertions inside named tests. How to do that depends on your chosen style. For example, in FunSuite, you'd write something like:

```
class MySpec extends FunSuite with PropertyChecks {
  test("give the test a name here") {
    forAll(x: Int, y: Int) {
      // make assertions here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're clearly the expert here, so I defer to your answer.  Is PropertyChecks an easier way of doing the equivalent of `check(forAll ...)`? My answer was based on the approach taught in the _Reactive Programming_ class last fall.

Comment: The main difference is PropertyChecks uses ScalaTest assertions or matcher expressions, whereas Checkers uses ScalaCheck's traditional Boolean expressions. If your property gets large, you'll need to insert ScalaCheck labels in your Boolean expression, which I think makes them a lot harder to read than assertions or matcher expressions.

Comment: @Bill.Venners Thanks for the explanation. I just had a chance to use PropertyChecks and have got to say it's far clearer than the approach I'd been using.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `forAll`, make the test class extend from `org.scalatest.prop.Checkers` and then in each test, call `check` with the Property to be tested.  In this case, "Property" probably means the `forAll` that you've created.

So I'm going to guess that currently you have a test class that looks like:

```
class ExampleSuite extends AssertionsForJUnit {
  val fractions = Table(
    ("n", "d"),
    (  1,   2),
    ///...
  )
  forAll (fractions) { (n: Int, d: Int) => // ...

  @Test def verifySomethingElse = ???
}
```

I believe what you need to do is extend from Checkers and move your `forAll` into a test.

```
class ExampleSuite extends AssertionsForJUnit with org.scalatest.prop.Checkers {
  @Test def verifyFractions = {
    val fractions = Table(
      ("n", "d"),
      (  1,   2),
      ///...
    )
    check(forAll (fractions) { (n: Int, d: Int) => ???)
  }      


  @Test def verifySomethingElse = ???
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is to create a FunSuite test with Matchers and TableDrivenPropertyCheck

**Example:**

```
import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatest.prop.TableDrivenPropertyChecks._

class CreateSpec extends FunSuite with Matchers {

  test("B-Tree-Create for different degree parameter value") {
    val params = Table(("degree", "result"),
      (0, Tree(Leaf(), 0)),
      (2, Tree(Leaf(), 1)),
      (1999, Tree(Leaf(), 1999)))

    forAll(params) {(degree, result) => Algorithms.create(degree) == result}
  }
 }
```